# May I say "get broken", "get awake", "get spread" instead of break, wake up, spread?

Tags: sentence-construction

I often say:

> — "Handle it carefully, otherwise it will get broken"
>   — "Be quiet, otherwise she will get awake"
>   — "Don't touch the oil, otherwise it will get spread" (here, the oil is already on the ground and touching it will spread it)

I could have said:

> — "Handle it carefully, otherwise it will break"
>   — "Be quiet, otherwise she will wake up"
>   — "Don't touch the oil, otherwise it will spread"

**I am in a habit of speaking the former. Do I need to correct myself?**

Comment: Is "get awake" correct ?

Comment: **My versions:** 1) Just 'Handle with care' because it *does* include what you want to convey! If you want to insist that it is glass, add - Handle with care, it's ***fragile***.  2) Shh, be quiet or else you'll *wake her up* 3) Be careful, or else you'll *spill* the oil.

Comment: @MaulikV, you're right. You should post that as an answer. Many people could benefit from it.

Comment: I may not. Because, that could be *one of the answers*. This question is primarily *opinion based*. @VarunKN And the OP is concerned about whether to use 'get X' So, the answer could be all different.

Comment: After edit and clarification: 3) Don't touch the oil or else it'll spread *further*.

Comment: Note that it's *Be quiet*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit of a touchy topic, because some of these are technically correct. However, in general, **yes, you should correct yourself**.

Looking at your provided examples:

often say:

> Handle it carefully, otherwise it will get broken.

This is technically correct. However, it is moderately strange, to the point that I would recognize that your first language isn't (American - can't speak for British here) English.

> Be quite, otherwise she will get awake

This one is definitely incorrect. This just isn't an idiomatic use of "awake." A lot of languages seem to have tricky wordings with "awake," but this isn't a possible phrasing.

> Don't touch the oil, otherwise it will get spread

While some may say that this is technically correct, I'd be willing to argue that this sounds strange enough to simply be marked incorrect. The strangeness is a result of the incongruency between the use of passive and active voice. It just doesn't work. If you're telling someone not to touch the oil, then it's weird to say that the oil will "get spread," because we already know by who it will be spread - it is the person you are saying that to!

Your corrected versions are much better. Use those when possible.

Comment: Strange! While advising someone with caution, I have heard using past participle way less common *(...will break over will get broken)*!

Comment: @MaulikV could you clarify that comment? You're saying that using the past participle is way less common (i.e., "get spread" is less common than "will spread" for this use)? I certainly agree with you there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should you should correct yourself. The former might convey the same meaning, but you will tend to make many mistakes when you use an additional verb, unnecessarily. I'm not a native speaker and I corrected many flaws whenever I could (I still do), and it really helped me. The advisable version of the sentences would be:

> "Handle it carefully, otherwise it will break"
>   "Be quite, otherwise she will wake up"
>   "Don't touch the oil, otherwise it will spread"

Good Luck.

Comment: I'd surely not use 'spread' for liquids. *Spill* is the word

Comment: @MaulikV Spill means that the liquid is thrown on the ground. I am talking about the situation where the liquid has already been thrown on the ground and now it will spread if touched.

Comment: Well,. in that case, you should *clarify* that in the question. @CoffeeDay

Comment: @MaulikV I don't need to. Spread and Spill are used for different situations which should be apparent by their meaning. As I said before spill means "throw" and spread is totally different than throw.

Comment: If a can is completely filled with oil, touching it will *spill* it and not spread it! 'Spill' does not include force what you need in 'throwing' it, by the way. @CoffeeDay Since your first example talks about handling things with care, the third example is most likely to go in that flow. Anyway, it's better to stay clear because then you get precise answer.

Comment: I know that. I didn't have a better word to describe spill hence used throw. Usage of the word spread in the question, is not wrong IMO. You seem to have read between the lines and assumed it should be spilling because it is liquid. @MaulikV

Comment: As you read my comment, 'spread' is correct in **that context.** We often say, 'oil was spread further in the sea'. @CoffeeDay